# Confirming compression is enabled for specific Hive tables

Tags: hadoop, hive

I need to benchmark a series of tables, some compressed and some not. I compress by setting:

```
hive> SET hive.exec.compress.output=true;
hive> SET mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec;
```

...and using INSERT OVERWRITE to populate a table. Is there a way to confirm via the command line (similar to DESCRIBE EXTENDED) that output compression is enabled for a particular table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following will show the path to the table files in hdfs

```
desc formatted <tablename>
```

hive> desc formatted cobtest;
OK
col_name    data_type   comment

## col_name              data_type               comment

batch_sk                int                     None
geo_cd                  string                  None
env_cd                  string                  None

## Detailed Table Information

Database:               default
Owner:                  steve
CreateTime:             Thu Nov 21 23:36:37 PST 2013
LastAccessTime:         UNKNOWN
Protect Mode:           None
Retention:              0
Location:               hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hive/warehouse/cobtest
Table Type:             MANAGED_TABLE
Table Parameters:
    numFiles                1
    numPartitions           0
    numRows                 0
    rawDataSize             0
    totalSize               473
    transient_lastDdlTime   1385105797

## Storage Information

SerDe Library:          org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe
InputFormat:            org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
OutputFormat:           org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
**Compressed:           No**
Num Buckets:            -1
Bucket Columns:         []
Sort Columns:           []
Storage Desc Params:
    field.delim             \t
    serialization.format    \t
Time taken: 0.203 seconds, Fetched: 34 row(s)

You can then do dfs -lsr and you will notice by the file extensions if they are compressed.

```
hive> dfs -lsr hdfs://localhost:9000/user/hive/warehouse/cobtest ;
-rw-r--r--   1 steve supergroup        473 2013-11-21 23:36 /user/hive/warehouse/cobtest/UDFPafCobIndTest.input**.tsv**
```

**UPDATE**  SNAPPY is the CODEC for compression. You still need to add the following:

```
SET hive.exec.compress.output=true;
SET mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec;
SET mapred.output.compression.type=BLOCK;
```

Comment: This is great javadba. I'm showing no compression on a table I loaded with output compression set to SNAPPY -- so the compression in desc formatted may be input or intermediate compression rather than output? My mapreduce.map.output.compress is undefined, perhaps this is what is reflected in desc formatted AND I may need this set in order to use compression in map functions? Thx...

Comment: I updated my answer with more info on how to do this.

Comment: I had these set as you show but Compressed shows NO. It must not be indicating output compression -- I'll test with map input and intermediate compression enabled and see if it changes. Thanks...

Comment: I am facing the same issue...though i add the above set commands, Compressed is NO for the hive table when i do desc formatted for that table, kindly inform how you resolved?

Answer (score 3):

When you exec `describe formatted orc_with_compress_setting_table` seeing something like this:

`Compressed: No` and feeling uncomfortable.

Here is the answer:

> The Compressed field is not a reliable indicator of whether the table contains compressed data. It typically always shows No, because the compression settings only apply during the session that loads data and are not stored persistently with the table metadata.

from: https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/impala_describe.html